# How do I protect phone number from bots

Tags: php, jquery

I want a phone number which display on public page will be protected. Example converts phone number characters to HTML entities and bots can't grab the number in plain text. Let me know the trick.

Comment: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/gracefulemailobfuscation/

Comment: You need to bear in mind that any kind of obfuscation you do here may have an impact on somebody using a screen reader.

Comment: Encode the phone number using BASE64 encoding and display the encoded text with info about the encoding. This is what I do to keep away the bots (and illiterate people) :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a...passing thought, though I'm not sure how practical it would be:

```
<span class="protectedNumber" title="01234567890"></span>
```

css:

```
span.protectedNumber:before {
    content: "Phone number: " attr(title);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SC6vL/).

---

**Edited**, in response to 'cross browser?' question in comments, to add a jQuery option to assist with those browsers that don't have the ability to deal with css-generated content:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
       $('.protectedNumber').each(
           function(){
               $(this).text('Phone number: ' + $(this).attr('title'));
           }); 
    });
```

Comment: simple and nice but cross browser?

Comment: I'll use this method. Thanks David.

Comment: nice! but a decent harvester should be able to harvest number because most numbers have a certain length, start with, etc. It would be safer to use a captcha image with your phonenumber I guess.

Answer (score 4):

some ideas

- display the phone number as an image
- use javascript to create and display the phone number
- throw in html tags in between the numbers (e.g. [span]) that visually makes no difference but makes it more difficult for the bot to recognize the phone number

Comment: +1 for adding HTML tags. It's a very simple method, and I'm not sure how sophisticated bots tend to be, but it'd probably throw the most basic bots off.

Answer (score 2):

- The first thing I'd think of is render an image.
- Use Javascript to obfuscate
- Obfuscate using a php function

Answer (score 2):

Try writing the number using ASCII:
http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

```
<html>
    <body>&#49;&#49;&#50;</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i guess the bots will most likely be able to convert it back

Answer (score 0):

Sure just print the phone number using words instead of numbers...

Comment: I have small space to write in `zero one nine three three eight four seven five`  :P

Comment: @blur - seriously though, it's hard to do this and retain an accessible site for those not using a standard browser.

Answer (score 0):

Create an image of the number, this will foil MOST bots, but some may have OCR, so obfuscate it.

ie: Good:

[image: phone# img]

Better:

[image: better phone# img]

The 2nd 1 better because like Captcha, the background contains "noise" that makes it hard for OCR enabled bots to harvest, but is as readable to human eyes..

The hard solution would be use Captcha or a simple PHP script to create the picture on the fly, but in most cases, unless you using alot of different #'s the "better" solution above easiest and quickest method, can do easy even in simple program like Paint in 5 min.

For the visually impaired, include a small link to an audio file (mp3) of you saying the number, if it linked properly, and accordingly, it should work.